# Can't figure out where to put require.config when using TypeScript, RequireJs, and Jasmine

Tags: requirejs, typescript, jasmine

I've been following the pattern for setting up TypeScript, RequireJS, and Jasmine that Steve Fenton describes here:

https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201407/Blog/Combining-TypeScript-Jasmine-And-AMD-With-RequireJS/

That pattern as really worked well and truly unblocked me (yay!), but I'm now at the point where I need to customize some settings for RequireJS but I can't seem to figure out where to put my `require.config` call.  Everywhere I've tried has caused breaks and regressions.  Here are the two approaches that seem most logical/promising

In SpecRunner.cshtml

```html
<script data-main="/Scripts/TypeScript/RequireJsConfig" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

In RequireJsConfig.ts

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: "../Scripts",
    paths: {
        jquery: "../jquery-2.1.3"
    }
});

// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
// Attempt 1: When I try it this way I immediately get this error
//
//     JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'config'
//
import TestLoader = require("Tests/TestLoader");
TestLoader.Run();

// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
// Attempt 2: When I try it this way, everything builds and runs without errors, but 
// Jasmine doesn't find any of the tests.  All I get is "No specs found" even 
// though I see the breakpoints on my "it" statements getting hit.
//
require(["Tests/TestLoader"], (testLoader) => {
    testLoader.Run();
});

// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

jasmine.getEnv().execute();
```

In TestLoader.ts

```js
import GuidHelperTests = require("Tests/T3/Helpers/GuidHelperTests");
import ObjectHelperTests = require("Tests/T3/Helpers/ObjectHelperTests");

class TestLoader {

    public static Run: () => void = () => {
        GuidHelperTests.Run();
        ObjectHelperTests.Run();
    }    
}

export var Run = () => TestLoader.Run();
```

In GuidHelperTests.ts

```js
import T3 = require("T3/T3Lib");

export var Run = () => {

    describe("GuidHelper tests", () => {
        it("GUID validator validates good GUID", () => {

        // etc. ...
```

My guess is that Attempt 2 doesn't work because of some kind of sequencing issue where the test discovery process is happening before modules are loaded, or something like that.  I'm just not versed enough in RequireJS to know what my options are here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to keep my configuration away from my application - you can pre-register the configuration like this, and it will be picked up by RequireJS when it loads. No need to add it to your first file.

```
<script>
var require = {
    baseUrl: "../Scripts",
    paths: {
        jquery: "../jquery-2.1.3"
    }
};
</script>
<script data-main="/Scripts/TypeScript/RequireJsConfig" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah!  A classic example of me now knowing what my options were.  I had no idea that was possible.  I seems a bit counterintuitive to define a require variable before loading require.js, but there's no arguing with success because it worked like a champ.  Thank you!